# How do I get all the members thumbnail avatar?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm using wordpress

How do I get all the members thumbnail avatar? just only their thumbnail avatar with 4columns by 4rows arrangement?

I have try this code:

```
<?php echo get_avatar(); ?>
```

but this is only for one person, I wanted all the members in my site?

Thankyou

Comment: First you need to find out how to select members

Comment: ♫ Go on, take the money and run ♫

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following way:
At first select user's list by the following function:

`get_users( $args )`

ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users

Then select members thumbnail avatar with the following code:

`get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size = '96', $default = '<path_to_url>' );`

ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Gravatars

Hope it could help you.